# python has multiple versions for different users

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was running my python script by `sudo`, it throws an exception, then I found the python versions are different as follows, I'm using CentOS 6:

```
[haifzhan@home]$ sudo python --version
Python 2.6.6
[haifzhan@home]$ sudo su -
[root@home ~]# python --version
Python 2.7.5
[haifzhan@home]$ python --version
Python 2.7.5
```

When I login as root or my username, the python version is 2.7, but when I use `sudo` to run, it is 2.6.

Can anyone tell me how to make them all to version 2.7, what should I configure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `python` means to call the first executable of this name in a directory pointed to by the `$PATH` environment variable.  Obviously your different users have different `$PATH` variables set.  I propose to have a look at them to understand which executable is called (it could be `/usr/local/bin/python` vs. `/usr/bin/python` or similar).  To view which you call, use `type python` once as your user and once as user `root`.

To call a specific Python binary you can call the explicit full path (e. g. `/usr/local/bin/python`).  This will call the same executable regardless of the value of the `$PATH` variable.

Alternatively you can configure your accounts so that both have the same binary first in the `$PATH` variable.

Also, you can try to call `python2.7` and `python2.6`; many installations symlink these to the corresponding binaries.

Comment: when I type `sudo su -` and then run python, it uses 2.7.14 but when I type `sudo python` it uses 2.7.5. How can make sudo python to use 2.7.14 version?

Comment: My first idea would be: deinstall the outdated 2.7.5.  There is no reason to keep it because from 2.7.5 to 2.7.14 there were only bugfixes, no feature changes.  Unless a program is relying on the existence of a bug, it should not need the outdated version.  But I understand that this could be hard, depending on your installation, etc.  So you can use full path names like `/path/to/2.7.14/python` or you could create symlinks like `/usr/local/bin/python2.7.newest -> /path/to/2.7.14/python` and then use `python2.7.newest` in your scripts.

Comment: Btw, `sudo python` doesn't perform a complete login as root, so you will still have the `$PATH` of your local user.  So I guess that user will also have 2.7.5 when calling `python`.  Maybe you just want to fix that user's `$PATH` to point to the newer version.

Comment: Is there any other way except to use the full path to the newer version?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend running `which python` and `sudo which python` to figure out which different scripts you are running. Also see this link
https://superuser.com/questions/600349/why-sudo-python-and-python-in-terminal-start-two-different-versions-python

Comment: I want to use python 2.7.14 so I edited `/etc/sudoers` file and added `/usr/local/python2.7` before `/bin` because `/bin` has `2.7.5` and `/usr/local/python2.7` has `2.7.14`. But still when I type `sudo which python` it outputs `/bin/python`